# Sum up only the second elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, integer, sum, tuples

Assuming I have this list of tuples: `[('3', '20'), ('1', '50'), ('2', '50')]`, how would I go about summing up only the second element in each tuple? So in this example, the sum would be 120. Also, would I have to convert the numbers to integers beforehand for the `sum()` function to work?

Answer (score 0):

If `l` is you list then:

```
sum(int(x[1]) for x in l)
```

Instead of `sum(...)` you can also use `sum((...))` or `sum([...])`. The former uses a generator expression, the latter creates a temporary list (list comprehension).

Comment: You do not have to enclose your generator expression into parenthesis neither brackets. `sum(int(x[1]) for x in l)` works just fine.

Comment: @Delgan Already modified while you wrote your comment. :-)

Answer (score -4):

you could try something like,

```
tup = [('3', '20'), ('1', '50'), ('2', '50')]
s= 0
for i in tup: 
    s+= int(i[-1])
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you. Sorry to bother with a following question, but could you clarify what the [-1] does? Thank you so much.

Comment: @kraderic When you use a negative index in a list, it counts from the end instead of the beginning. So `i[-1]` is the last element of the list.

Comment: @kraderic [-1] refers to the last one. In this case, it's the same as [1]. Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation here for explanation.

Comment: However, the question specifically says "the second element", not "the last element". In the example given they're the same, but that's not necessarily the case in general.

Comment: So "i" is referring to the individual pairs in the tuple, and then [-1] means it's only registering the last element in each pair?

Comment: @kraderic yes, by doing `for i in tup`, `i` is picking up one by one element of `tup`, so in first round `i = ('3','20')` and second round `i = ('1','50')` and so on. and then by doing `i[-1]` you get the last element or you could do `i[1]` which gives second element. Python counts from `0` so `i[0]` is first element.